# List[OptionT[Future, Int]] to OptionT[Future, List[A]]

Tags: scala, scalaz, monad-transformers

I'm building a `List` of `Int` using an an async computation for retrieving element:

```
(1 to n).map(anAsyncThingy).toList
```

where `anAsyncThingy` returns `OptionT[Future, Int]`

The result is hence of type `List[OptionT[Future, Int]]`

What I'd like to get now is an `OptionT[Future, List[A]]`

Here's my best attempt so far (I'll add some stubs, so that it can run in a REPL)

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def anAsyncThingy(x: Int): OptionT[Future, Int] = x.point[Future].liftM[OptionT]

val res = OptionT {
  Future.sequence {
    (1 to 3).map(anAsyncThingy(_).run).toList
  }.map(_.sequence)
}
res.map(println) // List(1, 2, 3)
```

The above works as expected, but I feel there's a lot of room for improvement using the proper scalaz constructs, instead of jumping in and out from monad transfomers.

How can I achieve the same result a in a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself, after some experimenting:

```
val res = (1 to 3).map(anAsyncThingy).toList.sequenceU
res.map(println) // List(1, 2, 3)
```

Yay for scalaz!

By the way, `sequenceU` is needed instead of `sequence` because scala isn't smart enough to figure out when you have

```
OptionT[M, A]
```

if you fix a type parameter (`M` to `Future` for instance)

```
OptionT[Future, A]
```

it has the shape of `M[_]`

The compiler keeps believing it has a `M[_, _]` shape, unless spoonfed (with a nasty type lambda)

Here's where scalaz's `sequenceU` kicks in and works around this issue using `Unapply`. More on the subject [here](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Unapply.html).

#### Update

As per phadej's comment, `sequence ∘ map ≡ traverse`, so this can be made even more concise with `traverseU`:

```
(1 to 3).toList.traverseU(anAsyncThingy)
```

The same idea of `sequence` vs `sequenceU` applies to `traverse` vs `traverseU`, of course.

Comment: As a sidenote: `sequence ∘ map ≡ traverse`, so I'd rather write: `(1 to 3).toList traverseU anAsyncThingy`